# change textContent of SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object, svg

i have a situation were i want to call this same svg function somewhere else so i do:

```
function second() {
    one();
}
```

but in function second() i want to change function one() textContent.

```
function second() {
    one();
    document.querySelector("#textError").textContent = ("new text");
}
```

when i run this function it works but only if i load function one() first to create the svg. and then i can call function second() to change the text. but i want to call function second() first. it gives me:

console error: Unable to set property 'textContent' of undefined or null reference

Comment: So you want to change the text of something that does not exist? That's not possible. But you could pass the `textContent` as parameter to `one()`. It would look similar to `one(text) { text = text || 'defaultText'; //... }`

Comment: What is `svgError`? can you add the html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a parameter to function `one`.

```
function one(textContent){ 
    ....................
    ....................    
    var t = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','text');
    t.setAttribute("id", "textError");
    t.textContent = textContent?textContent:"hello";
    svgError.appendChild(t);
    ....................
    ....................
}
```

Now, send the new text as parameter to `one` function from 'second` function.

```
function second() {
    one("new text");
}
```

**Edit:**
To get the text from some other section and pass, code as shown below.

```
function second() {
    var newText = this.getText();
    one(newText); // one(this.getText());
}
```

Comment: and what if i want to pass a value that it needs to get from another page. eg function second() { one(this.gettText(......);} the text that it gets is a string. but i dont want to manually type it in the argument i want it to fetch the string